# Sockets: How would Peer to Peer chat work?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to make a P2P chat without manually adding users IP Address.

---

These scripts would send and receive UTF-8 message with UDP packets by manually specifying IP address.

```
# Send

# Let's say this code is executed from PC1.

import socket

PC2_IP = '192.160.4.169' # IP address is not valid, it is just for example. 
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hey there!"


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
             socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Now as example let's execute Receiver script from PC2.

```
    # Receive

    # Let's say this code is executed from PC2.

    import socket

    ip =  socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 

    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp.bind((ip, 5005))


    while True:
        data, addr = udp.recvfrom(1024)
        print data
```

This would work without any problems, The message would be received instantly after script executed.

---

But in theory how would i make a P2P chat without manually specifying IP addresses?

How would i make application get both users hostnames? Do i need to specify IP Addresses with `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` in both sender and reciever scripts?

[image]

---

If i need some extra necessary modules which one of them would it be? Can i use P2P module for sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1:1 case the first program doesn't need to know the address of anyone else. It just starts and waits. The second program needs to know the address of the first. As soon as it sends a "hello" the first program now knows the address of the second via recvfrom.

If you want **no** known addresses, well it stops being a Python question. Now you need to learn about autoconfiguration and network discovery protocols. Multicast? DNS Service Discovery? Bonjour?

That gets complicated real fast. There's a good reason why so many chat and chat-like Internet systems have a single server that everyone knows the address of.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, maybe i would make a central database, that logs ip addresses, multicasting method was a good idea by the way!

Answer (score 0):

maybe help this link [P2P Berry Tella=BT](https://cs.berry.edu/%7Enhamid/p2p/framework-python.html)
For this exist and python source(if need!)
Hope help you!